# Execution failed for task ':calculator:compileKonanKotlinArithmeticParserIphone'

Tags: ios, kotlin, kotlin-native

Well I am try to run the Calculator sample from the kotlin-native repo.

Followed these steps:

To build and run the sample do the following:

1. Open samples/calculator/calculator.xcodeproj with Xcode.
2. Open the project's target through project navigator, go to tab
   'General'.   In 'Identity' section change the bundle ID to the
   unique string in reverse-   DNS format. Then select the team in
   'Signing' section. See the Xcode .  documentation for more info.
3. Now build and run the application on a connected iPhone with Xcode.

But when I try to build the application in Xcode I get the following error and the log to it is below:

...
...
...

```
The target is not enabled on the current host: linux . 
Target 'linux' of artifact 'libgit2' is not supported on the current host . 
The target is not enabled on the current host: linux . 
The target is not enabled on the current host: linux . 
The target is not enabled on the current host: linux . 
The target is not enabled on the current host: linux  
Target 'linux' of artifact 'libcurl' is not supported on the current host . 
The target is not enabled on the current host: linux . 
The target is not enabled on the current host: linux
The target is not enabled on the current host: linux
The target is not enabled on the current host: linux
The target is not enabled on the current host: linux
The target is not enabled on the current host: raspberrypi
Target 'linux' of artifact 'sdl' is not supported on the current host
Target 'raspberrypi' of artifact 'sdl' is not supported on the current host
The target is not enabled on the current host: linux
The target is not enabled on the current host: raspberrypi
Target 'linux' of artifact 'tetris' is not supported on the current host
Target 'raspberrypi' of artifact 'tetris' is not supported on the current host
The target is not enabled on the current host: linux
The target is not enabled on the current host: mingw
Target 'linux' of artifact 'ffmpeg' is not supported on the current host
Target 'mingw' of artifact 'ffmpeg' is not supported on the current host
The target is not enabled on the current host: linux
The target is not enabled on the current host: mingw
Target 'linux' of artifact 'sdl' is not supported on the current host
Target 'mingw' of artifact 'sdl' is not supported on the current host
The target is not enabled on the current host: linux
The target is not enabled on the current host: mingw
Target 'linux' of artifact 'Player' is not supported on the current host
Target 'mingw' of artifact 'Player' is not supported on the current host
The target is not enabled on the current host: mingw
:calculator:checkKonanCompiler
:calculator:compileKonanKotlinArithmeticParserIphone FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':calculator:compileKonanKotlinArithmeticParserIphone'.
Classpath of the tool is empty: konanc
Probably the 'konan.home' project property contains an incorrect path.
Please change it to the compiler root directory and rerun the build.
Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a very similar/same issue, and the [Kotlin folks figured out the issue](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/issues/1119#issuecomment-350011002).

1. `cd` to the `kotlin-native` project root
2. Run `./gradlew dist crossDist`
3. Open Xcode and run the project.

[image: calculator demo running on an iPhone 8 Plus]